# Print Bangla in pythone

Tags: python, unicode

I declare some variables in Bangla without any syntax error.

But when I want to print it, its gives me the error.

`SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xff' in file D:/Project/Python Tutorials Repo/condition/condition.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details`

This is my script it Github: https://github.com/banglaosc/condition/blob/master/condition.py

[image: Cant Print Bangla]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code editor, you can see that your Unicode change with another format (UTF-16LE). Try to convert from UTF-16LE to UTF-8 from the bottom right corner. It's working for me.

[image: Unicode UTF-8 change picture]

Answer (score 1):

The encoding is at the bottom right in that PyCharm screenshot: UTF-16LE. The problem is that Python 2 will assume a file is ASCII (per [PEP 263](http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)), and Python 3 will assume UTF-8 (per [the tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/interpreter.html#source-code-encoding)).

Try switching the file encoding by clicking the **UTF-16LE** button at the bottom right.

Comment: I write the code you provide at the top of my code and still the same error.

Comment: @SushenBiswas Hmm, can you switch it to utf-8 instead?

Comment: @SushenBiswas maybe try removing the BOM? I'm not sure how to do that though, sorry

Comment: This is wrong. UTF-16 encoding **cannot be used** in Python. The problem is the bootstrapping procedure: in principle Python would have no problem with switching to UTF-16 to read the rest of the file, but it *cannot read the encoding declaration itself* - as it *defaults* to UTF-8, and UTF-16 is not ASCII-transparent - and thus cannot know to switch.

Comment: The strange thing to me is that PyCharm offers the option to edit UTF-16 files in the first place, given that it's an IDE specifically for a language that doesn't support them.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: The following applies to python3.5+ this will not work in python2.7

When I run your code I do not get that error. Pycharm show it as an error, but the python interpreter has no issue with the characters. The exception actually raised when running this is `TypeError` because the variable `জুকারবার্গ` is an int, and you are trying to use the `+` on it with a string. The following will execute with no errors.

```py
বিল_গেটস = 20
জুকারবার্গ = 30
ওয়ারেন_বাফেট = 35
ইলন_মাস্ক = 10


if বিল_গেটস > জুকারবার্গ:
    print(str(বিল_গেটস) + "বেশি ধনি")
else:
    print(str(জুকারবার্গ) + "বেশি ধনি")
```